# Deploy war without a version number to artifactory

Tags: maven, war, artifactory

We are using maven to create and deploy a war to artifactory. We currently have the build working great with the finalName tag:

```
<build>
    <finalName>mywar</finalName>
</build>
```

This builds the final artifact `mywar.war`. However when we deploy to Artifactory, the version number will be appended to the war like `mywar-1.0.0.war`. Now when we download and deploy the artifact from Artifactory, the context-root of the app will be http://localhost/mywar-1.0.0 rather than the desired http://localhost/mywar.

Can we configure artifactory to now append version numbers to war files?

Ideally the artifact would be stored as: http://artifactory:8080/artifactory/repo/com/myapp/mywar/1.0.0/mywar.war

Configuring a context-root from the app itself doesnt seem like a good idea since the config would be container dependent. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Artifactory does not add any version number to the deploy file. The version is probably added by the maven build.
Regarding the example that you gave, it actually should be:
http://artifactory:8080/artifactory/repo/com/myapp/mywar/1.0.0/mywar-**1.0.0**.war
Can you please elaborate on what exactly the issue is?

Comment: You should add the approprivate contextroot definition in your war file that will solve the problem. Apart from that artifacts in a repository are allways named based on `${artifactId}-${version}.${packaging}` which can't be changed.

Comment: Sounds good, that is what we were thinking, just wanted to see if there was a way around it. Well look into the context-root or having the automated tool rename the wars are needed. Thanks for the help